# Keep value after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this category checkbox where if I select certain values it will display `div size` but also in the same time when I select the checkbox it will submit the form. The problem is if I add `this.form.submit()` , the code below won't work and the form won't submit the value, but if I don't add it, the code will work.
How do I display div size and submit the form at the same time?

```
function getIds(checkboxName) {
 let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
 let ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkBoxes)
           .filter(ch => ch.checked==true)
           .map(ch => ch.value);
 return ids;
}

$(".category").on('change', function() {
 this.form.submit(); 

 let catIds = getIds("category[]");

 $.each(catIds, function(index, value){
    if (value == '1' || value == '2') {
        $("#size").show();
    } else if (value == '3') {
        $("#size").hide();
    }

 });
});
```

Comment: Use ajax to submit form ?

Comment: no, im not using ajax

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a racing problem. The form gets put into a different thread by the browser and gets handled first before the rest of the javascript is able to finish.

A quick (but dirty) hotfix for me is usually to use the setTimeout() method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

That way the javascript can work it's magic and afterwards the form gets submitted.

Comment: the form or the `#show` that i should set the timeout?

Comment: I didn't test your code myself, but I think the submit()-function needs to be executed a little bit delayed.